# How to do selective labeling using ggplot2 key feature instead of label

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, tooltip

Hello is there a way to display the data labels only for specific data of my dataset? I used `key` instead of `label` in order to create the tooltip but I cannot make it work. As a final result I want to be able to display labels of my choice as now and also have some data labels always displayed.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)
    library(ggplot2)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("iris")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$iris <- renderPlotly({
          # set up plot
          p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length", 
                                        y = "Sepal.Width",
                                        key = "Species")) +
              geom_point()+
geom_text(data=subset(iris, Sepal.Lenth > 6),
            aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,label=Species))

          # get clicked point
          click_data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "select")
          # if a point has been clicked, add a label to the plot
          if(!is.null(click_data)) {
              label_data <- data.frame(x = click_data[["x"]],
                                       y = click_data[["y"]],
                                       label = click_data[["key"]],
                                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
             p1 <- p1 + 
                 geom_text(data = label_data,
                           aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
                           inherit.aes = FALSE, nudge_x = 0.25)
          }
          # return the plot
          ggplotly(p1, source = "select", tooltip = c("key"))
      })
      }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length", 
                              y = "Sepal.Width",
                           text = "Species")) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_text(data=subset(iris, Sepal.Length > 6),
        aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,label=Species))

ui <- fluidPage(
        plotlyOutput("iris")
      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
           output$iris <- renderPlotly({
           # get clicked point
           click_data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "select")
           # if a point has been clicked, add a label to the plot
           if(!is.null(click_data)) {
              pos <- click_data$pointNumber+1
              label_data <- data.frame(x = iris$Sepal.Length[pos],
                                       y = iris$Sepal.Width[pos],
                                       label = iris$Species[pos],
                                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
              p1 <<- p1 + 
                 geom_text(data = label_data,
                           aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
                           inherit.aes = FALSE, nudge_y=.1)
          }
          # return the plot
          ggplotly(p1, source = "select", tooltip = c("text"))
      })
      }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: how do you specify the x criteria (Sepal.Length >6) here?

Comment: @firmo23 Sorry, I forgot two lines of your code. See the updated  answer.

Comment: Iti s fair to accept your answer as it solves the initial issue but my actual dataset is not iris but it is given as input from csv file and is named rt(). While Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width come from input$lx1 and input$lx2 respectivelly. So could I use them instead of iris and Sepal.Length and Width to get the same result? I understand that this is a diffrent question.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503889/replace-iris-dataset-with-dataset-that-comes-as-csv-input-in-shiny-app-and-maint